# NullPointerException quando criando uma View no Android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Estou criando uma `Activity` em Android, cujo código está [aqui](http://pastebin.com/sjT80S2P), e estou obtendo um `NullPointerException` próximo da linha

```
final TextView txtResult = new TextView(this);
```

Obtive o seguinte dump do stack:

```
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887): Process: br.com.colorcalc, PID: 887
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{br.com.colorcalc/br.com.colorcalc.Calculator}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3429)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3496)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:622)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:617)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:613)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at br.com.colorcalc.Calculator.<init>(Calculator.java:26)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
05-07 09:12:57.180: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  ... 11 more
```

Será que tem algo relacionado com meu método `onCreate`?

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
            btnCalc.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {      
                            result = "#" + rst1 + remainderR + rst2 + remainderG + rst3 + remainderB;
                            txtResult.setText(result);
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: `final` significa que você está declarando uma constante ao invés de uma variável, logo só poderá atribuir o valor à `txtResult` em sua criação. Sobre o NPE, você tem TextView chamado `txtResult` no seu xml?

Comment: Experimenta assim:
`final TextView txtResult = new TextView(ATuaActivity.this);`

Comment: Tenho sim Math. E inclusive utilizei-o para mostrar o resultado de uma equação. Vou incluir a linha no post principal.

Comment: Jorge, mesmo com a alteração o problema continuou.

Comment: Se entendi bem seu dump, `br.com.colorcalc.Calculator` é sua `Activity`, correto? O `<init>` significa que o código está sendo executado no construtor. Você está mesmo fazendo tudo isso dentro do construtor da `Activity` ou eu entendi algo errado? Se estiver criando as views dentro do construtor, o conceito está errado, você deveria criar as views (manualmente, ou através do método `setContentView`) dentro do `onCreate` da `Activity`, ou outro lugar parecido.

Comment: Sim, Calculator é minha Activity. No ínicio do projeto, eu estava criando meu código dentro do onCreate, porém tive um erro de double "" que segundo o que encontrei no SO em inglês, pode acontecer quando um código muito grande é inserido dentro dele. Portanto, optei em criar o código dentro de um outro método, objeto ou void.

Comment: Então, @leo.saldanha, não conheço um limite para linhas de código dentro de um método. Talvez seu erro era de uma `String` muito longa? O correto é mesmo deixar a criação das views dentro do `onCreate`. Se puder, mande um exemplo maior do código, mesmo que por link.

Comment: Você conhece algum site para upload de código para que eu possa te passar o link?

Comment: Quantas linhas tem? Se não tiver muitas (<= 200), pode colocar na pergunta. Caso contrário, eu conheço o http://pastebin.com/ onde você pode colar códigos para compartilhar. Mas coloque o link na pergunta, também.

Comment: Tá aqui: http://pastebin.com/sjT80S2P

Comment: Apenas lembrem-se de formatar a pergunta ao final da discussão para evitar links externos. E tentem fazer uma pergunta sucinta, que seja útil para futuros visitantes e que não fuja da pergunta original. @leo.saldanha, recomendo a leitura de dois links: [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na linha 40 do código postado

> btnCalc.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()

Você está utilizando `btnCalc`, mas ele não foi atribuído antes. Antes de utilizar `btnCalc` falta algo como

```
btnCalc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
```

Mais um detalhe, para converter um número inteiro `x` para sua notação em hexadecimal, é possível simplesmente fazer isso:

```
Integer.toHexString(x)
```

Comment: O fato de criar o evento no botão no XML e adicionar esse código à classe atrapalha em algo?

Comment: Se você já colocou no XML, então, não precisa colocar o `setOnClickListener` no cóldigo, aliás, nem deveria ;) Agora, se tirar do XML, aí pode colocar no código, sem problemas.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: Depois tente dar uma otimizada naquelas conversões de hexadecimal, como te falei ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Final** - Para declaração de constantes.

Agora em questão a boas práticas, essa sua linha do código.
`final TextView txtResult = new TextView(this);`

No meu caso eu mantenho as boas práticas e faço o seguinte:
 - Declaro todos objetos de interface que vou usar, de maneira global (logo abaixo do public class).
 - 
 - Dessa maneira: `private TextView txtResult;`
 - Dentro do método onCreate() eu referencio que a variável `txtResult` da seguinte maneira:

```
txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID_DO_OBJETO);
```

Assim dessa maneira você pode usar o txtResult em várias partes do código.

Outra boa prática que uso é o seguinte, no `XML` do layout, no código do botão, eu acrescento :

```
android:onClick="METODO"
```

obs: dentro do `onClick=""` o método deve ser escrito sem o ().
Dessa maneira não é necessário fazer oque você fez, que no caso foi:

```
btnCalc.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()  {   
    public void onClick(View v){
        result = "#" + rst1 + remainderR + rst2 + remainderG + rst3 + remainderB;
        txtResult.setText(result);  
    }
});
```

Comment: Dá um olhada no dump dele... Aparentemente isso tudo está acontecendo dentro do `br.com.colorcalc.Calculator.<init>`, ou seja, o construtor da classe (o que não seria o melhor lugar para instanciar as views). E sobre o `final TextView txtResult ...`, não tem problema declarar uma view como `final` para ser utilizada dentro do método. Só colocaria como um campo da classe, se realmente precisasse utilizar a view em mais de um método da `Activity`

Comment: Mas essa maneira que eu disse como boa prática é o aconselhável né? do que colocar as views no onCreate.

Comment: Sobre a formatação do seu código, você pode aprender um pouco lendo esse tópico: [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/3117)

Comment: Não entendi bem a pergunta do seu comentário, @EnzoTiezzi... Se quiser, depois vem falar comigo no primeiro horário, que eu estou meio tranquilo! :)

Comment: ok @carlosrafaelgn, depois da uma olhada no face, te deixei uma pergunta, Valeu!!